# sort a column and customize it after sorting

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there any way so I can put Other in country at the bottom of my table.
I sorted the table with `total_customers DESC` But I want the Other in country at the bottom?

```
    country        total_customers  total_sales avg_sales   avg_order_val
0   Other                15          1094.94    7.448571    72.996000
1   USA                  13          1040.49    7.942672    80.037692
2   Canada               8            535.59    7.047237    66.948750
3   France               5            389.07    7.781400    77.814000
4   Brazil               5            427.68    7.011148    85.536000
5   Germany              4            334.62    8.161463    83.655000
6   United Kingdom       3            245.52    8.768571    81.840000
```

Desired output :

```
    country        total_customers  total_sales avg_sales   avg_order_val
0   USA                  13          1040.49    7.942672    80.037692
1   Canada               8            535.59    7.047237    66.948750
2   France               5            389.07    7.781400    77.814000
3   Brazil               5            427.68    7.011148    85.536000
4   Germany              4            334.62    8.161463    83.655000
5   United Kingdom       3            245.52    8.768571    81.840000
6   Other                15          1094.94    7.448571    72.996000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a case expression in the ORDER BY clause.

```
ORDER BY CASE country WHEN 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, total_customers DESC
```

Comment: It's not changing `Other` is still at the top

Comment: @sai_636 Then maybe you could update your question with the actual query used to produce the sample result? I guess my assumption that the headers represent columns might have been wrong. I guess maybe you are running some aggregate query.

Comment: sorry! My mistake it's working. I got the desired output. I didn't use it properly the first time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM total_customers ORDER BY (CASE WHEN country = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), country  DESC
```